# How to render react on server-side with an api?

Tags: rest, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, mern

Just to make it clear, I'm using the MongoDB, Express, React and Node stack.

I'm trying to learn react.js right now. I got the basics right and I am able to code a simple react app with a router. I've also tried server-side rendering a simple react app and it also works perfectly. However, I'm kind of stuck now that I want to make a full app with a rest api and server-side rendering.

1) I don't know how I should go about separating the api and the react code in the server file. Would starting off by listing the api calls and then do the server-side rendering work?
Like so:

```
app.get('/api/whatever', function(req, res) {
    //get whatever
});
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    //math routes and renderToString React
});
```

2) Also, the reason I couldn't even test the above, is that when I try to run the server with nodemon it throws an error because it doesn't understand the react code, how should I go about this? Should I somehow configure nodemon to read es6 or ignore it or configure webpack to run the express server ?

3) The final question that could clear this whole story quite easily. I've tried finding an answer but got many conflicting ones instead. Are the google crawlers capable of crawling a React app? I'm learning server-side rendering for SEO, is that all really necessary?

Sorry for the long question, looking forward to reading your answers.

Comment: What are you giving as response in second app.get function?

Comment: app.get("*",function(req, res){
     ReactRouter.match({routes:AppRoutes, location:req.url},

      function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps){
        if (err) {
          res.send(500, err.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
          res.send(200, ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />))
        } else {
          res.send(404, 'Not found')
       }
    });
});

Comment: I'm going to add the whole function as an edit in the question. This does not look right...

Comment: yes and what is the error nodemon showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I do it the same way you do in your code example in the project I'm currently working on – I match * and then use React Router to render different pages. [I wrote a blog article about this, with code examples](https://ebaytech.berlin/universal-web-apps-with-react-router-4-15002bb30ccb#.u1i33gno4).
2. in the setup I have, I use webpack to compile my backend code, just like I do with the frontend code. I use the watch mechanism to listen for code changes and automatically restart the node server after recompiling. No need for nodemon.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const serverConfig = require('webpack.config.server');

const compiler = webpack(serverConfig);
const watchConfig = {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
    ignored: '**/*.scss'
};

let serverControl;

compiler.watch(watchConfig, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);
        if (err.details) {
            console.error(err.details);
        }
        return;
    }

    const info = stats.toJson();

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
        info.errors.forEach(message => console.log(message));
        return;
    }

    if (stats.hasWarnings()) {
        info.warnings.forEach(message => console.log(message));
    }

    if (serverControl) {
        serverControl.kill();
    }

    serverControl = spawn('node', [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/polly-server.js')]);
    serverControl.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} [LOG] ${data}`));
    serverControl.stderr.on('data', data => console.error(`${new Date().toISOString()} [ERROR] ${data}`));
});
```

3. yes, Google crawls client-side React code, but server-side rendering is still a good idea, because crawl results may be inconsistent, especially if you load parts of the page dynamically after Ajax calls

Comment: Thank you for your answer that is exactly what I was hoping for. However, in the demo from your blog post, you fetch data from the git hub api. Would having an api living inside the server.js file work? Wouldn't the '*' conflict with '/api' since it handles ALL the requests? I guess I'm going to try it out and see what happens.

Comment: No conflict, just make sure your * match comes last, the order matters